# Where to set java heap options (e.g. -Xmx) for Tomcat 6 under Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, java

I'm running Tomcat using the tomcat6 package from Ubuntu 9.04, which makes a daemon out of Tomcat using jsvc. I'd like to know the proper way to set Java heap options like `-Xmx` for Tomcat. I'd like to put the configuration wherever is most stylistically correct, and wherever is least likely to be overwritten by Ubuntu package updates.

The options I see right now:

- Hard-code them somewhere in `/etc/init.d/tomcat6`.
- Hard-code them somewhere in `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh`.
- Create a line in `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh` to set CATALINA_OPTS to have the desired flags, and then export CATALINA_OPTS as an environment variable. (This looks like it will get picked up by `catalina.sh`.)

The last option sounds like the best one, and it's advocated (without explanation of why) at [Increasing Java's heapspace in Tomcat startup script](https://serverfault.com/questions/121038/increasing-javas-heapspace-in-tomcat-startup-script). But I wanted to get a second opinion. Anyone want to confirm that there isn't a better way?

Answer (score 37):

At least on Ubuntu 10.04, /etc/init.d/tomcat6 sources /etc/default/tomcat6 if it exists. That's where I put my overrides, and I believe it's generally the "approved" way to make such changes.

Comment: /etc/default/tomcat6 is the proper place

Comment: +1 Configuration should always be done in `/etc` if possible.

Comment: On CentOS, the location I found was /etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf

Comment: On CentOS 6.4, `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf` is a large file and I didn't want to put my personal customizations in there, so I created `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` and sourced it in `/usr/sbin/tomcat6`. Hope this helps CentOS users (yes, I know the original question was for Ubuntu).

Comment: @khylo yep, took me a little while to figure it out. seems in CentOS the /etc/init.d/tomcat6 is calling /usr/sbin/tomcat6 which is NOT calling catalina.sh but simply calls the tomcat bootstrap class directly (as opposed to the Ubuntu /etc/init.d/tomcat6 that is calling catalina.sh)

Comment: Works on Debian too, even after all this time!

Answer (score 16):

If you look in your installation's bin directory you will see catalina.sh or .bat scripts. If you look in these you will see that they run a setenv.sh or setenv.bat script respectively, if it exists, to set environment variables. The relevant environment variables are described in the comments at the top of catalina.sh/bat. To use them create, for example, a file $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh with contents

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx512m"
```

For Windows you will need, in setenv.bat, something like

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768m
```

This is true from tomcat 5.5 through 7.
Original answear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progra

Comment: Works well for systems without the /etc/default/ include, e.g, FreeBSD.

Answer (score 7):

Look for **/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf** which has the likes of JAVA_OPTS ready and waiting for you to uncomment (but only if you have it at all, I'm using Centos not Ubuntu).

```
# System-wide configuration file for tomcat6 services
# This will be sourced by tomcat6 and any secondary service
# Values will be overridden by service-specific configuration
# files in /etc/sysconfig
#
# Use this one to change default values for all services
# Change the service specific ones to affect only one service
# (see, for instance, /etc/sysconfig/tomcat6)
#
...
#JAVA_OPTS="-Xminf0.1 -Xmaxf0.3"
```

Comment: This seems to be correct for CentOS / yum / RPM version of tomcat. For the Ubuntu / apt-get package the setenv.sh is the right way to go AFAIK

Comment: yes, KCD is correct, for centOS tomcat6.conf works well. Checked with the command **ps aux | grep tomcat** it shows the parameter with the values i set.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way I've found so far is to edit /etc/init.d/tomcat6 and add this at the top of the file:

```
# local config settings
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms5000m -Xmx13000m
```

The other options I outlined in my question don't seem to work. After studying the script and experimenting some more, I now doubt that /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh and /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh play any role in tomcat startup with the tomcat6 Ubuntu package. Instead; the /etc/init.d/tomcat6 completely replaces any work that might normally be done by catalina.sh/startup.sh.

I'm still a little worried about losing these config options in some future package update, but I guess if that happens it'd be pretty easy to restore them.

Comment: Can this be set (exported) in the .bashrc for whatever user you want tomcat to run as ? [please excuse horrid grammar]  That would survive updates to Tomcat package, etc.   I'm assuming the "run-as" facility in init will start normal shell for that user and pick up the assignment.

See also http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/